# Curl Command to c# code

Tags: c#, curl, asp.net-web-api

I have following CURL command

```
curl.exe -k  "relevance=value" --user admin:pass https://10.221.22.13:34323/api/query
```

corresponding to this, I have written following c# code

```
    private async void RunClient(string _address, string username, string password)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string authString = username + ":" + password;

        try
        {

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authString);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            string valueString = "value";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("relevance", valueString);

            // Send a request asynchronously and continue when complete
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);

            // Check that response was successful or throw exception
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

The CURL command is working fine in cmd but the c# code throws Bad Request (400) Error.

Where I am wrong ?

Thnx in Advance.

Comment: What is your webserver saying it received

Comment: in exception, it shows bad request

Comment: No - I asked what your webserver recieved - not what the error you see is

Comment: I don't have access to web server. All I know is Web API is working with the CURL command but throws bad request exception with above c# code.

Comment: if you cant see the access/error logs it really can be a harder quest if you cant confirm whats been sent

Comment: Try using a tool like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to compare the http traffic between curl/c#

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Post request and "relevance=value" should be passed in content body instead of header, here is the modified code :

```
  private async void RunClient(string _address, string username, string password)
    {
        // Create an HttpClient instance
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string authString = username + ":" + password;

        try
        {
            //add authentication to header
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authString);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            string valueString = "value";

            var con = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("relevance", valueString)
            });

            // Send a request asynchronously and continue when complete
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(_address, con);

            // Check that response was successful or throw exception
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```